# Classic ASP.NET Developer Demanding SourceSafe; Looking for Supported Alternative

Tags: git, svn, visual-sourcesafe

Our classic ASP.NET developer is complaining of problems with TortoiseSVN he's been having.  He was comfortable in his old job with SourceSafe and refuses to listen to me when I recommend  Team Foundation Server as a supported alternative.

I won't install SourceSafe because its deprecated, but I need to find a solution that is apparently as simple.  What should I do?

Is there a Git GUI that would be similar enough to SourceSafe that he would like it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no SCMs that have the look and feel of SourceSafe (apart from SourceOffSite by SourceGear, but that connects to SourceSafe repositories, so not an option for you anyway) that I am aware of.

Your developer will have to suck it up and learn how to use a modern SCM - the best you can do is give him options. Both SVN and GIT have Visual Studio integration (via different add-ins or plugins to Visual Studio) in addition to the Tortoise* shell integration. Show him what is available.

I can understand that he doesn't want to move with the times (Classic ASP developer, after all...), but in this case, he has to.